# Visual Studio 2019 .EDMX Update Model From Database Does not work

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

@ajcvickers I am also facing the same issue.. My web project was created in VS 2015 then after 1 years I start the development on 2017 and just few days back we jumped to 2019 but seems like the same steps working in VS2017 but not in VS2019  -- Steps was : Taking the "Update model From Database".

I can see the procedure successfully added to

1. GSModel.Store -> Stored Procedure/Functions
2. GSModel -> Function Import
3. GsModel - > Complex types

but not able to find the same procedure in code.

Can you please help and any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I also switched to Visual studio 2017 to 2019 recently and today i got same issue while i was trying to refresh my `.edmx` Model for a table update. It was not adding new class for that table. After lot of google research i found someone in Chinese language complained regarding this issue as he says problem on- `visual studio 2019 Preview 1`. But since now its fully released problem should be fixed however it seems its still persists. Some Microsoft official blog user also replied that they will fix it asap on this blog post.

[Chinese post is here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/400455/vs-2019-preview-1-ef6-edmx%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E6%97%A0%E6%B3%95%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98.html)

What can we do now?

My advice is- just have some delay of 2/3 month before using any latest technology release. For now switch back to `Visual studio 2017` and this problem never happens on it. Best of luck.

Comment: Now the solution has been released on visual studio 16.2 version. 
It's now working perfectly.. 

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for sharing latest update @vijaysahu

Comment: Getting this on 16.8.3